# Scala: How to require that a type have parameterless constructors

Tags: scala

In Scala, in the following context:

```
class MyClass[T] {
}
```

How can I limit T to be a class with a parameterless/default constructor?
thanks

Comment: @cchantep already explains the standard Scala approach but to answer the question literally: you can't.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Would rather use a typeclass approach, requiring to have a parameter-less factory.

```
trait Factory[T] {
  def create(): T
}

class Foo() {
}

object Foo {
  // Define Factory instance for Foo
  implicit val factory: Factory[Foo] = new Factory[T] {
    def create() = new Foo()
  }
}

class MyClass[T : Factory] {
  // accept only T with Factory[T] available
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what i had in mind but definitely one of the ways to do this.